# Graficar un histograma, me salen numeros del tipo 0e+00

Tags: r, rstudio

```
tipo <- as.factor(c("Diabetes", "Hipertension", 
                    "Obesidad", "Diabetes e hipertensión", 
                    "Cancer","Asma", 
                    "Artritis", "Anemia", "Alzheimer", 
                    "Otras enfermedades distintas a las anteriores"))
Frecuencia <- c(645618, 2817066, 1855885, 8176991, 1022807, 4576819,4617275, 2779312, 1102457, 2679007)
ocurridos <- data.frame(tipo, Frecuencia)
hist(ocurridos$Frecuencia)
ggplot(ocurridos, aes(x=Frecuencia, y=..density..))+
  geom_histogram(bins=15)
```

Y de esas dos formas me aparece en el eje de las x numeros tipo: 0e+00, 6e+06 y no entiendo a lo que me hace referencia

Comment: Bienvenid,a mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor añade el código de lo que estas intentando, sino estamos a ciegas. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ya añadí el código, por si te es posible checarlo, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Por defecto, R maneja una forma de determinar cuando usar la notación científica versus la fija que hace que valores de tu ejemplon se muestren como se muestran, el comportamiento es: **Si la versión en notación científica es más "corta" que la notación fija se usa la primera**. Esto se puede modificar agregando una "penalidad" a este calculo para que la notación exponencial solo se use con valores más altos. Esta "penalidad" esta configurada por defecto en 0 y podemos manipularla mediante: `options(scipen=<penalty>)`, este valor se mantiene durante toda la sesión y eventualmente deberá ser reconfigurado en una nueva sesión (se podría agregar al archivo `.Rprofile` para evitar esto).

Veamos primero que valores tenemos:

```
getOption("scipen")
[0]

c(1,10,100, 1000, 10000, 100000)
[1] 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02 1e+03 1e+04 1e+05
```

Ahora lo modificamos agregando esta penalidad:

```
options(scipen=3)
c(1,10,100, 1000, 10000, 100000)
[1]      1     10    100   1000  10000 100000
```

El número de `scipen` no tiene que ver con la cantidad de dígitos a mostrar es básicamente un valor que deberás experimentar para establecer el umbral en el que R determina usar la notación científica, a números más grande, mayor este valor