# Recodificación datos al importarlos de SPSS

Tags: r, importación

Estoy intentando importar datos desde spss a R.

La tabla en formato spss al exportarlo tiene una columna de números tipo:

```
 9749027
 9729530
 106367
 599875
```

Pero al incorporarlo con R usando este código:

```
   Julio <- read.spss("Datos_julio.sav", use.value.label=TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE)
```

o este código

```
   Julio <- read_sav("Datos_julio.sav");Julio<-dim(Julio)
```

la variable se me recodifica a esto:

```
   9.749027e+06
   9.729530e+06
   1.063670e+05
   5.998750e+05
```

¿Cuál es mi problema?
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Adrián ¿los datos deben ser numéricos? entonces la importación está funcionando correctamente, R por defecto muestra ciertos números con notación exponencial, es decir, es un problema de visualización del dato, no del dato en sí. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455040/graficar-un-histograma-me-salen-numeros-del-tipo-0e00/455142#455142

Comment: Gracias Patricio, he utilizado options(scipen=3) y R ha sido más restrictivo a la hora de importar datos en formato exponencial o no. Muchas gracias